# Permanently replacing a function

Tags: r

Could someone explain the following code?  I'm replacing the layout function in the graphics package with my own version, but it seems to re-appear magically

```
env = environment( graphics:::layout )
unlockBinding( "layout" , env = env )
assign( "layout" , function(){} , envir = env )
lockBinding( "layout" , env = env )

# this still shows the original layout function!  how is that possible?
layout

# this shows function(){} as expected
graphics:::layout
```

Comment: all - I apologize for all of the questions related to environments lately.  This is proving to be a complicated and confusing subject.  If there are any recommended reading materials (other than the standard R PDFs which are not very helpful) please let me know!

Comment: Don't apologize; I've learned a lot from them myself. I don't have it myself, but I've heard that the [Chambers](http://www.amazon.com/Software-Data-Analysis-Programming-Statistics/dp/1441926127/ref=sr_1_9?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325110851&sr=1-9) book is sort of the R programming (as opposed to statistical computing) bible.

Comment: I actually just ordered that book an hour ago. =)  can't wait to down it.  Thanks for the words of encouragement, joran!

Comment: I have a few notes at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Scoping - I've noted all your recent stackoverflow posts and they will contribute to the next version (when I get a chance to write it)

Comment: sweet!  looking forward to the next version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning your new version of `layout` to the graphics **namespace**, which is what is returned by `environment(graphics:::layout)`. You *instead* want to make the assignment into the attached graphics **package** (i.e. the environment appearing as `"package:graphics"` on your search path).

In your example, when looking for `layout`, R searches down the list of attached packages returned by `search()`, and finds the original `layout` in `package:graphics`, before it ever gets to function you've assigned into `namespace:graphics`.

The solution is simple, requiring only a change of environment assigned to `env` in the first line:

```
# Assign into <environment: package:graphics>
# rather than <environment: namespace:graphics>
env <- as.environment("package:graphics")

unlockBinding( "layout" , env = env )
assign( "layout" , function(){} , envir = env )
lockBinding( "layout" , env = env )

# Now it works as expected
layout
# function(){}
```

**A bit more elaboration, that may be useful to some:**

```
search()    # Shows the path along which symbols typed at the command 
            # will be searched for. The one named "package:graphics" 
            # is where 'layout' will be found.

# None of these return the environment corresponding to "package graphics"
environment(layout)
environment(graphics::layout)
environment(graphics:::layout)

# This does
as.environment("package:graphics")
```

Comment: thanks, Josh!  So why does `env = environment( graphics:::layout )` not work but `env <- as.environment("package:graphics")` does?

Comment: See also `assignInNamespace` - things get more complicated if you want to change S3 methods.

Comment: @SFun28: The first gets you the namespace environment which only graphics uses, the second gets you the graphics package environment which everything else uses.  (I'm not sure how this would affect other attached packages that import graphics)

Comment: If you don't need to, it seems preferable not to assign into the namespace, as you could break any other functions (mostly likely in the package) that call the function, 'expecting' to find another version of it.

Comment: Yes, a general meta comment is that there are very very few places that it's appropriate to break into an environment and modify the contents.

Comment: agreed.  I'm slaying dragons this time. =)  The whole concept of namespace versus package versus imports is still terribly confusing to me.  Hopefully some more reading will clear that up.

Comment: hadley, josh - why do `ls(environment(layout))`, and `ls(as.environment("package:graphics"))` show a similar but not identical set of symbols (aside from the fact that they are different environments)?  Maybe the larger question is what's the purpose of the namespace environment and why does it show more functions than the package envrionment?  For example, I see text.formula in the namespace environment but not in the package environment.  `text` appears in both.  When would `text` in the package environment get executed and when would `text` in the namespace environment get executed?

Comment: @SFun28 - There are several questions in there. hadley has [a few relevant notes here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Namespaces).  To answer your last couple of questions, functions in a namespace are generally only seen/accessed/executed during the evaluation of calls to other functions in the same package. If you call `text` with a formula for an argument, it'll **first** look in `namespace:graphics` for a function called `text.formula`. Why? Because that's the environment of `text`, as seen by typing `text` and pressing return.

Comment: `text` can be found from the command line because it is exported from the namespace, but `text.formula` can't be similarly found. (You can of course access it by typing `graphics:::text.formula`). Finally, `text` in the namespace will be found/accessed/executed by any other function in `package:graphics` or `namespace:graphics` that itself calls `text`, since all of the functions in the graphics package have `namespace:graphics` as their environment.  I fear this hasn't been too helpful, but let me know if it does clarify anything. Otherwise, just wait for Chambers -- help is on the way!

Comment: Thanks, Josh!  This has been quite helpful.  I'm going to re-read these SO posts/comments after I've read Chambers and I think it will all come together nicely.