# Save package settings between sessions

Tags: r, package

Is there a definitive way to save options or information pertaining to a certain package between sessions?

For example say somebody made a game and released it as an R package.  If they wanted to save high scores and not have them reset each time R started a new session what would be the best way to do this?  Currently I can only think of storing a file in the users home directory but I'm not sure if I like that approach.

Comment: Not for an R package per se, but it is fairly typical on in the nix world to store this kind of thing in a hidden file or hidden directory in the users home directory. On windows you might use an applicate data directory or the registry.

Comment: I've had the same question myself, I thinkt he key may be in this SO post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661526/permanently-replacing-a-function

Comment: "somebody made a game and released it as an R package" <- Errror, does not parse

Comment: @AriB.Friedman http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sudoku/index.html

Comment: @AriB.Friedman Also see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fun/index.html

Comment: Phew!  I was worried my productivity would tank after "helpful" suggestions of time-wasters by @BrianDiggs and Dason, but fortunately neither RStudio nor R run through a terminal supports interactive graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be an approach.  I created a dummy package with a dummy function (any function I create is bound to be a dummy function) and a data set I called `scores` that I set as follows:

```
scores <- NA
```

Then I created the package with the scores data set.

Then I used the following to change the data set from within R.

```
loc <- paste0(find.package("new"), "/Data")
unlink(paste0(loc, "/scores.rda"), recursive = TRUE, force = FALSE)
scores <- 10

save(scores, file=paste0(loc, "/scores.rda"))
```

Then when I unloaded the library and re loaded agin the data set now says:

```
> scores
[1] 10
```

Could this be modified to do what you want?  You'd have to have it save in between somehow but am not sure on how to do this without messing with `.Last` function.

**EDIT:**

It appears this option is not viable in that when you compile as a package and use lazy load it saves the data sets as:

RData.rbd, RData.rbx, not as .rda files.  That means the approach I use above is kinda worthless in that we want it to automatically be recognized.

**EDIT2**
This approach works and I tried it on a package I made.  You can't do lazy load of the data and you have to either explicitly use `data(scores)` or use `data(scores)` inside of the function you're calling.  I also assigned `scores` to `.scores` int he global.env the first time it was created and used `exists` inside the function to see if it exists.  If `.scores. existed I assigned that to scores within the function.  Once you unload the library and laod again you never have to worry about that again.

Maybe an alternative is to save this as a function somehow that can be altered using Josh's advice here: [Permanently replacing a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661526/permanently-replacing-a-function)

Comment: What's your take on `.onUnload`? I haven't tried it but it should be run for all packages when R is closed, right?

Comment: You could re-save `scores` anytime that it is modified (assuming that isn't very often). Then you don't have to worry about saving it "at the end"

Comment: I'll have to play around with it but this seems like it will do what I want.

Comment: I don't see why the approach is worthless.  I don't see any reason I would need to lazy load the data.

Comment: How not dason or do you make the function load the data?

Comment: I decided that since this isn't actually data I want available and is just used internally by the package to instead put the data in inst/extdata as recommended in [Rexts](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages).  I prefer saveRDS and readRDS as well so I'm using those for now instead but if anybody sees problems with that let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no way to store settings without saving them to disk or a database, some way or another. It can be done silently though by putting the code below in your `~/.Rprofile`. However, if you have packages that save settings in other ways than using `options` you need to add them manually.

I know this is exactly what you said you did not want, but it might spark some debate at least.

```
.Last <- function(){
    my.options <- options()
    save(my.options, file="~/.Roptions.Rdata")
}

.First <- function(){
    tryCatch({
        load("~/.Roptions.Rdata")
        do.call(options, my.options)
        rm(my.options)
    }, error=function(...){})
}
```

To my suprise `try(..., silent=TRUE)` gives a warning on startup if `~/.Roptions.Rdata` does not exist, which is why I used `tryCatch` instead.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this without requiring the user to modify their .Rprofile?

Comment: You could make a package for it and put the above code in `.onLoad()` and `.onUnload()` in `zzz.R`, but then you'd still need to load that package everytime you start R.

Answer (score 1):

The modern answer to this problem is well explained at https://blog.r-hub.io/2020/03/12/user-preferences/

I think I will be trying the hoardr package! Here is an example that worked for me :)

```
x <- hoardr::hoard()
x$cache_path_set("yourpackage", type = 'user_cache_dir')
x$mkdir()

scores<-data.frame(
  user=c("one","two","three"),
  score=c("500,200,1100")
  )
save(scores,file = file.path(x$cache_path_get(), "scores.rdata"))

x$list()
x$details()

#new session
x <- hoardr::hoard()
x$cache_path_set("yourpackage", type = 'user_cache_dir')
x$list()
x$details()
load(file = file.path(x$cache_path_get(), "scores.rdata"))
```

PS - you can see a working example in the rnoaa package found on at github "opensci/rnoaa". Check their R/onload.r file! I can expand if needed.